# How to delete the rows, where data is null?

Tags: mysql, database

> As per the query, the row from 1 to 11 should be deleted, but didn't. What is the reason?

```
select * from tblPerson;   
delete from tblPerson where Age = NULL
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Age = NULL -> Age is null

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags here. SSMS is an IDE for SQL Server, and has nothing to do with MySQL. Please [edit] your question to tag correctly.

Comment: DELETE from tblPerson WHERE Age IS NULL
Alternatively, if you have blanks and NULLs: DELETE from tblPerson WHERE ISNULL(Age,'') = ''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
DELETE FROM tblPerson WHERE Age IS NULL
```

`Age IS NULL` checks whether Age is a NULL value.

`Age = NULL` is checking whether Age is equal to NULL which will never be true.

Comment: Yeah it works, please help me with the reason that why my query is giving such output.

Comment: As I have written, Age = NULL will never be true. You should use Age IS NULL